# binding an arraylist to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hallo there

I am adding object(books) to an arraylist as I add them to a database that is situated in a web service. My idea is to display these books in a gridview(in the deffault.aspx) by obviously binding it to the arraylist. The problem I have is that the gridview is situated in deffault.aspx, and the procedure for adding the books to the arraylist is on a different page entirely and thus I can't seem to access the data source programaticaaly from the gridview.
Is there a way of binding the arraylist data to the gridview, even if they are, like in this case situated on different pages?

Kind regards

Comment: please share your code details for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refactor a bit.  Take all the code that's responsible for manipulating arraylists and books, and put that into some sort of business logic layer that can be accessed from *any* of your pages.

Comment: Adam is seconding Adam on this - you need to refactor unless you pull that grid out into a user control and contain all of that logic in the user control, but generally you want the code to access this data outside of your pages anyways. just because you 'can' put this code in a page doesnt mean it should be there, you should have separate code classes as Adam mentioned above that can be accessed from any page.

Comment: I never met an Adam I didn't like :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new .cs file in your site. If you're running the older style web site, put it in your App_Code folder, otherwise you can place it in any subfolder:
Books.cs

```
public class Books {
        public static ArrayList GetBooks() {

            return new ArrayList() { "Book1","Book2","Book3"};
        }
 }
```

Then, in your aspx pages codebehind you can bind the gridview to this new method:

```
protected void Page_Load() {
    GridView1.DataSource = Books.GetBooks();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Adam Rackis's suggestion is good as well. Separating your business logic to a separate project is almost always a good idea. Try this first though.

Comment: +1 - this *is* my suggestion - it doesn't necessarily have to be a separate project if it's small enough; the main thing is to get that code out of the web pages.

Comment: Arianule I see you are new to SO. It's good practice to mark a response as the answer if you felt it was helpful (of course, don't if you feel otherwise). Thanks